# Whats the proper way to ensureIndex index mongodb field on a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, mongodb, multidimensional-array, mongodb-query

I have data in mongodb something like so. There is a collection of cats. The cats are sorted into different categories and ranked 1 through 100. One cat might be located in 2 or more categories. There are 1000s of categories.

**COLLECTION**: "cats"

**KEYS**:

```
rank.category1 = 1; // ranked 1st in category #1
rank.category2 = 13; // ranked 13th in category #2
rank.category425 = 50; // ranked 50th in category #425
```

**QUESTION**:
If I want to do a find() to return all "cats" that have a "rank" in "category2" where $exists => "rank.category2" what is the proper way to index this? Can I just put a simple ascending index on "rank" collection or do I need an index on all 1000+ category* keys? Is there a better way to store this information or an easier way to index it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about ...

```
rank.categories = [1, 2, 425];
rank.category = {
    1 : 1,
    2 : 13,
    425 : 50
}
```

You can index `db.collection.ensureIndex({"categories":1})`. Now you can search through categories and get ranking of each when you find one.

Comment: Yeah I think this might be the only way to do it. Doesn't look like you can index array keys... only array values. What does the query look like to return all cats in the collection that contain a single category id?

Comment: I found it. Its an easy find() with ... {categories:435}